# conda Update issue?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Recently I have facced to open adaconda navigaator. I have tried to resolve the issue by updateing anaconda from anaconda navigator. Its anaconda 2.6.11 version.

```
C:\Users\Billal>conda update conda
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\users\billal\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)
>
> File "c:\users\billal\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)
>
> File "C:\Users\Billal\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe__main__.py", line 9, in 
>    File "c:\users\billal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\markdown__main__.py", line 130, in run
>       markdown.markdownFromFile(**options)
>
> File "c:\users\billal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\markdown__init__.py", line 529, in markdownFromFile
>       kwargs.get('encoding', None))
>
> File "c:\users\billal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\markdown__init__.py", line 428, in convertFile
>       input_file = codecs.open(input, mode="r", encoding=encoding)
>
> File "c:\users\billal\anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 895, in open
>       file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'update'
>
> C:\Users\Billal>